# Connecting centroids of lines sharing same intersection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, intersection, line, centroids

I have this street network of the center of Turin (IT), composed by lines representing streets, and black points representing intersections.

[image]

I have computed the centroids of each line and displayed these as red points. Now I would like to connect the centroids (red points) of each line that share the same intersection (black points) as in the "B" scheme of this picture:

[image]

The attribute of the intersections, that are the black points, are simple Ids:

[image]

Whereas in the attributes of the lines representing the streets I have the Ids, the start node (that is the Id of the black point where the line begin) and the end node (the Id of the black point where the line end.)

[image]

Do someone have an idea about how this can be done?

I've thought about pharsing the lines start points over the end points and vice-versa, but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Is non-QGIS of interest for you?

Comment: Well if you have any idea it would help me figure out how to do it in QGis!

Comment: I have an idea of how to perform this in QGIS, but could you share some sample data of the three layers for testing?
Hopefully this hasn't impacted your thesis!

Answer (score 1):

The script below assumes there are 3 feature layers:

1. Point layer - nodes or street junctions
2. Polyline layer - street segments. Associated table has 2 fields of integer type to store sequential number of from and to node.
3. Polyline layer called 'connections' to store results.

Only essential part of the script shown below, i.e. no error handling, parameters assignment, etc:

```
## LIST TO STORE STREET SEGMENT MIDDLE POINT AND CONNECTED NODES ids
        bigList=[]
## ITERATE THROUGH SEGMENT TABLE AND AAPEND ABOVE LIST
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theLinksLayer, ("SHAPE@",linksFromI,linksToI)) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                        pC=row[0].centroid
                        bigList.append((pC,row[1],row[2]))
        del row, cursor

## ARRAY TO STORE PAIRS OF POINTS AT INTERSECTING SEGMENTS
        theList=arcpy.Array()        
## ITERATE THROUGH EACH NODE and CALCULATE NUMBER OF CONNECTED SEGMENTS
        for i in xrange(nNodes):
                pList=[]
                for triple in bigList:
                        if i in triple:
                                p=triple[0]
                                pList.append(p)
                nCon=len(pList)
                if nCon>1:
## ITERATE THROUGH COMBINATION OF SEGMENTS AND CONNECT THEIR MIDDLE POINTS
                        for a in itt.combinations(xrange(nCon),2):
                                theList.removeAll()
                                theList.add(pList[a[0]])
                                theList.add(pList[a[1]])
                                l=arcpy.Polyline(theList)
                                curT.insertRow((arcpy.Polyline(theList),1))
```

Input sample, nodes labelled by their sequential number:
[image]
Output sample:
[image]

Comment: Hello @FelixIP! thank you a lot for you help, I'll try the script and report back if it works for me!

Comment: Hello felix, I'm trying to run the script, copying and pasting it into the console but I get an error: ![IMAGE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7085068/Schermata%202014-12-15%20alle%2015.28.18.png).

Comment: This is ArGis solution. It is not going to work in any other environment