# Connecting points with lines

Tags: qgis

I have the centre of some buildings (polygons) and the road network of the area. The road network will be used as a pipe network as well. So I want to connect each building to the main transmission line, namely the road line. I am looking for a tool that connects the centre of the buildings which I already have as points with the polyline in the shortest distance possible.

I am using QGIS 2.4.0. I dont have GRASS GIS on my PC.

Comment: It is unclear what you need. Do you perhaps want to connect the polygon centers into a new road network? Or maybe they already lie on a network and you seek paths between them along that network? Or maybe you want to connect each center to the nearest point on an existing network?  (And if so, why does it matter that these are polygon centers and not just arbitrary points?)

Comment: @whuber I'm curious if they're referring to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123713/how-to-connect-centroids-of-lines-sharing-the-same-intersection-in-qgis)

Comment: No, the points are not on the lines. They are stand alone points

Comment: @user41257 Can you provide a lot more detail to your question. Please refer to [this nice write up](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) that might help us and yourself to find a solution to your problem!

Comment: @dassouki I believe that's a different question. It appears this asker just wants to generate 'service lines', and lacking any specific data they're using the building/polygon centroid as one terminus and the road network in place of a dedicated pipe network as the other. One possible issue that comes to mind is if the shortest path from a building to the nearest road happens to pass under another building. But it sounds like we're just looking for a rough approximation here. So really this is just 'from any given point, draw the shortest line to the nearest line', but context is helpful imho.

Comment: @user41257 please provide a lot more detail in your question, as well as what have you tried so far? perhaps screen shots of the data? What is your overall objective? etc

Comment: @dassouki This is exactly what I need; to draw and calculate the shortest distance from any point to the nearest line on QGIS 2.4.0. Is there something you could suggest on this?